# No matching function error

Tags: c++, linux

I have this code,  which I am trying to compile on `Linux` with `G++-4.7`:

```
TermToGeneCount *tg = new TermToGeneCount();
TermToGeneCount *tgn = new TermToGeneCount();
Dag<int64_t>* dags = new Dag<int64_t>();
//....
getTermToGeneCount(nwPar.getAnnotationRetriever(),dags,tg,tgn);
```

Where the getTermToGeneCount is defined in the same namespace as:

```
void DefaultNwBuilder::getTermToGeneCount(const JavaWrapping::javaAnnotationRetrieverWrapper& annRetriever, Dag<int64_t>* dags, TermToGeneCount* tg, TermToGeneCount* tgn) const{
    //..
    }
```

When I compile I get this error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘cnw::DefaultNwBuilder::getTermToGeneCount(const JavaWrapping::javaAnnotationRetrieverWrapper&, Dag<long int>*&, TermToGeneCount*&, TermToGeneCount*&)’
note: candidates are:
```

I think that the problem is with the second parameter, becouse if I delete it (both from the call and from the method definition) it works.

Could you please help me?

Comment: Can you please show the _complete_ and _unedited_ error message? What candidates are there?

Comment: Is the call to getTermToGeneCount in a method in DefaultNwBuilder?

Comment: No candidates were provided, from the error message I've just purged file name and line numbers. @MikeP yes, it is.

Comment: Works generally: http://ideone.com/ZQoBrc You need to provide more context, as @JoachimPileborg mentioned.

Comment: Do you include the header file where the `DefaultNwBuilder` class is defined (and the `getTermToGeneCount` function declared`)? It _is_ declared in the class?

Comment: Did you try to replace `int64_t` with `long int` when creating the `Dag` object?

Answer (score 2):

Possibly a 32-bit versus 64-bit platform compile kind of issue.  The `long int` in the error does not necessarily map to an `int64_t`...

Comment: That would be a linker error wouldn't it? I doubt that would manifest at the compilation stage.

Comment: Also, gcc replaces the `int64_t` with the typedef'd type in the error message - see http://ideone.com/5ry6F0

Comment: On the other hand, OP mentions that it works when the parameter containing `int64_t` is removed ...